# Non-mutating array push method equivalent

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'd like to add a new element to an array in a non-mutating way. In JS, I can do this:

```
var new_arr = arr.concat(3)
```

instead of this:

```
arr.push(3)
```

How can I do the same thing in Ruby? The `concat` method in Ruby is mutating.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
new_arr = arr + [3]
```

Answer (score 8):

I'll add another solution using array splats that might seem less awkward:

```
new_arr = [*arr, 3]
```